# UITableView displays data then crashes

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I'm making an iOS that lists the files in the Documents dictionary. I want to display this data in a UITableView, the problem is that it's not working.
It loads the data in to the view. *Then* the application freezes and calls `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`
This is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    timesRun = 0;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath error:nil];
    [bundleRoot release];
    NSLog(@"Count: %i",[dirContents count]);
    return [dirContents count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewData cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    int Locatation = indexPath.row;
    Locatation++;
    cell = [tableViewData dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCells"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"]autorelease];
    }
    //cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell: %i",Locatation];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dirContents objectAtIndex:timesRun];
    timesRun++;  
    return cell;
    NSLog(@"Did return");
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewDat didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was sort of like Mario's answer. `[dirContents count]` returned a *higher* value than the amount of times it could add an object from the array.
In other words it was a Out of Bounds error.

Comment: Yes. But I think the out of bounds comes from your timesRun++ which increases every time cellForRowAtIndexpath is called (which is every time the table needs to check for the currently displayed cells which is most likely more often than the size of your array). You really don't need to keep a counter yourself (and it also doesn't work the way you did). If you have any more follow up qstns, feel free to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

This displays a basic misunderstanding of the concept of the table view data source.

My suggestion:

Create an array that contains the files outside any tableview methods. Then you use that array to feed the tableview.

Use array.count to return numberofrowsatindexpath. 
Also, on providing the cells at cellforrowatindexpath, don't use iterations/counters. The tableview ask for each element of your array itself using the indexpath argument. You access it like this:

id object = [array objectArIndex: indexPath.row]

And you then use the objects attributes to set the labels of the cell.

Please read a tutorial on tableviews. I recommend itunesU Paul hegarty's lectures. They're really great.

Ps. You release the bundleRoot object in numberofrowsinsection, which you don't retain (or use at all) which is most likely causing your crash.

**Edit:**

With a little more spare time, I retouched your code:

```
//code not tested/written in xcode. Might contain typos

//in your .m file
//in your (private) interface

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSArray *dirContents;

//in your implementation

@synthesize dirContents=_dirContents;

-(NSArray*) dirContents {
  if (!dirContents) {
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   _dirContents = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath error:nil] retain];
  }
  return _dirContents;
  //note that if you want to "refresh" the contents you would have to
  //release _dirContents and set it to nil or implement this differently
}

-(void) dealloc {
  [_dirContents release];
  //....
  [super dealloc];
 }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return [[self dirContents] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

  cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCells"];
  if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCells"]autorelease];
  }

  cell.textLabel.text = [[self dirContents] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

  return cell;
  //  NSLog(@"Did return"); //this never gets called by the way
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not releasing dirContents while using that.I am sure you are not doing but just cross check with your code.